# 3 hard drives fail with 2 enclosures and 2 pcs

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

here is the jist of my very strange problem...

I had an old laptop hard drive(120gb toshiba) which was pulled working out of a laptop and placed into an enclosure. it worked fine for a while and saw little use only as a backup drive. one day, it started clicking. plugging it in just resulted in click....click....click... and nothing else. I assumed the drive was dead(it was about 5 years old) and put it in a drawer. about 6 months later the harddrive in my current laptop(500gb seagate) was getting errors and failing diagnostics, I couldn't warrenty it yet so I ordered a new hard drive(250gb wd blue) under the assumption that I would stick the new drive into my laptop... load windows and continue having the functional laptop I needed. the old drive which hadn't failed yet would go into my enclosure and I could backup my data from there. once I pulled the drive from the pc it went right into the enclosure with the same result. click...click... click... So I thought maybe my enclosure is defective... so I ordered a new enclosure, a different brand too. same result from both drives. finally the day to warrenty came so I pulled the 250 out.. replaced the old 500 and it booted up perfectly. putting the 250 in both enclosures wielded the same results this was a barely month old drive.

I have tried multiple cables. 2 different computers(an asus i5 and a sony vaio p3). on both windows 7 and puppy linux. and 3 hard drives. I must be missing something unless I have just gotten super unlucky on enclosures. all the hard drives seem to work in a pc but not in any enclosures. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen in external enclosures when they are not receiving enough power.
Using first generation USB this happens quite often.

You might want to use an external power supply + the enclosure

I know - not quite as easy as it should be.

Comment: the enclosures have the dc jack but its not labeled... is 5v what I need? and I could see this being an issue on the old p3 laptop... but the new one is barely 6 months old...

Comment: check with the mfg of the enclosure - 5v is a good guess - but the real pain is knowing the right layout... +/- vs -/+